# Is this possible: $\frac{dy}{dx} \not= 0$ when $y=0$, under some conditions

Tags: calculus

Can a continuous, nonnegative, nonconstant function $y=f(x)$ have a nonzero derivative at a value $x_0$ where $y(x_0)=0$?

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Comment: Don't take it personally, maybe there is some vagueness to the question.

Comment: I don't see why this question should be closed on the grounds that it's "off-topic" for the site. It is clearly a question about math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the function is nonnegative, it reaches a minimum at $x_0$ and therefore it's derivative at $x_0$ must be $0$, if it exists.

The function $f(x)=|x|$ is nonnegative, $f(0)=0$ and $\not\exists f'(0)$ so $f'(0) \neq 0$.

So to answer your question, if the derivative is not $0$ at such point it MUST not exist.

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take any function $y=f(x)$ that is differentiable. Assume at $x=a$  we have $y=f(a)=0$, and  $\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=a}=0$. Now consider the new function $y=f(x)+(x-a)$.This function  still takes value $0$ at $x=a$, but the derivative there is $1$. (You can replace $(x-a)$ by $C(x-a)$ for an arbitrary constant and make the derivative assume that value $C$.)

Comment: But the new function may not be nonnegative.